# Running one test file in native mode and another test file in non native mode by using one command

Tags: testcafe

I want to run sampleTest.ts in native automation mode and sampleTest2.ts in non native automation mode.

This is the command that I run in the terminal but it runs both test files in non native mode:

**node --max-http-header-size=9999999 node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe -c 2 'chrome --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage' testcafe/tests/sampleTest.ts testcafe/tests/sampleTest2.ts --disable-native-automation**

Is it possible to run sampleTest.ts in native mode and sampleTest2.ts in non native mode via one command?